# How to find the containing egg file from Python class?

Tags: java, python, module, egg

From Python 2.6 it is possible to run an egg file directly from python command line, by incorporating a **main**.py file.

Now... is it possible to detect in runtime if the current executing python code is running directly from an egg and obtain the path of it ?

I'm trying to mirror similar Java functionality where it is possible to get the containing jar from a class through Java's ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a nicer pythonic way to do this otherwise by hand:

```
puria@spaghetti:~$ cat __main__.py 
 import zipfile, os
 module_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
 print "Is this an egg? ", zipfile.is_zipfile(module_path)

puria@spaghetti:~$ python __main__.py 
 Is this an egg?  False

puria@spaghetti:~$ zip example.egg __main__.py 
 adding: __main__.py (deflated 15%)

puria@spaghetti:~$ python example.egg 
 Is this an egg?  True
```

Hope this is useful and I actually understood your question.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect! Sorry but no credit now to vote answer up :-(